# How to auto advance slides in beamer without full display mode?

Tags: beamer, transition

To advance the slides automatically, after so many seconds, it seems that you need to have the full display mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> on PC) while using `beamer`.
How can I have the same effect when the PDF file  does not occupy the whole screen but just is one of many windows?

(Reason: I want to show something else at the same time as the slides.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *Beamer* built-in `\transduration` only works in full screen mode. But you can achieve auto-advancing in non-full screen mode too using some document-level JavaScript (`pdflatex`, AdobeReader):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% doc-level JavaScript functions
\immediate\pdfobj{<<
  /S/JavaScript/JS (
    setPageTimeOut=function(d){
      return app.setTimeOut("turnPage()", d*1000.);
    }
  )
>>}
\edef\setPageTimeOut{\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}

\immediate\pdfobj{<<
  /S/JavaScript/JS (
    turnPage=function(){
      if(this.pageNum==this.numPages-1){
        this.pageNum=0;
      }else{
        this.pageNum++;
      }
    }
  )
>>}
\edef\turnPage{\the\pdflastobj\space 0 R}

\pdfnames{
  /JavaScript <<
    %name tree mapping doc. level JavaScript functions to object numbers
    /Names [(setPageTimeOut) \setPageTimeOut (turnPage) \turnPage ]
    /Limits [(setPageTimeOut) (turnPage)] %first and last in alphab. order
  >>
}

%macro to set per-page timeout
\def\turnPageAfter#1{%
  \pdfpageattr{
    /AA <<%
      %additional page-open/close actions
      /O <</S/JavaScript/JS (var to=setPageTimeOut(#1);)>>
      /C <</S/JavaScript/JS (app.clearTimeOut(to);)>>
    >>
  }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
   \turnPageAfter{2}
   \frame{
     This page times out after 2 s.
   }

   \turnPageAfter{4}
   \frame{
     This page times out after 4 s.
   }

   \turnPageAfter{1}
   \frame{
     This page times out after 1 s.
   }

   \turnPageAfter{5}
   \frame{
     This page times out after 5 s.
   }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Very useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use *View -> Page View -> Single Page* and proceed with PgUp for acroread
There ist also the *One Full Page* button for direct use.

Comment: @almer The pages have their own timing, I don't want to interfere with that and use PgUp, PgDn etc. So page 1 is to be there for say 10 seconds and the next page for 15 seconds and so on. I want the pages to proceed as set internally, not manually.

Comment: @Grahn Thank you. This was of tremendous help.